# How do I fetch the attributes/values from JSON using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript function `create(tagName, options)` and the options variable is a JSON object. like this:

`{id: 'test_id', class: 'test_class'}`

I would like to know how to get the 'id/class' part of the json object.

Comment: Just be aware that `class` is a reserved word in ECMAScript spec. Nothing will break yet since it is not reserved yet in implmentation, but it is a good idea to put the keys in quotes as well. `{'id': 'test_id', 'class': 'test_class'}`

Comment: @Chetan - agreed. Recommendation: use `klass` instead of `class`.

Comment: sorry just realized. I don't want the value, I want the actual id bit (I want to be able to pass in anything to as a JSON Object). Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: What you have is a JavaScript object literal. It isn't a valid JSON representation. JSON-encoded objects always have the quotes around their member names, and both these and other strings in JSON always use double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dot or square bracket notation:

```
var obj = {id: 'test_id', klass: 'test_class'};
alert(obj.id + ' ' + obj.klass);
```

or:

```
var obj = {id: 'test_id', klass: 'test_class'};
alert(obj['id'] + ' ' + obj['klass']);
```

You can use a for...in loop to get the keys, e.g.:

```
var obj = {id: 'test_id', klass: 'test_class'};
for(key in obj) {
    alert(key);   
}​
```

​
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2p2gw/5/

Comment: Be aware that `class` is a *future reserved word*, and some implementations may throw a `SyntaxError` exception if used as an `Identifier`. Safari is a good example, the demo will not work.

Comment: @CMS - I know this (but thanks). I actually commented under the question. I will change to 'klass'.

Answer (score 0):

```
options.id
options.class
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other examples, you can get the properties out using the `object[...]` syntax:

```
options["id"]
options["class"]
```

Also watch out with your example JSON. To be strictly valid JSON there should be quotes around the keys:

```
 { "id": "test_id", "class": "test_class" }
```